# Is there any reason a Google Apps Script wouldn't run for specific people?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

So here's my problem: I've made a Google Apps Script that I've put on an HTML page to make a form. The script then pushes the data to a Google Sheets document that is **accessible to anyone, even anonymous**. However, the only person the script won't run for is the script administrator. I've tried with many different computers, and mine was the only one which didn't run.

I've also cleared my cache, and checked to see if the source code showed the correct script destination, and sure enough, it did. Is there anything that I've been doing wrong?

Thanks for the help, guys.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a script to make a form, it may be better to just use a Google Form and then link it to a spreadsheet. Then if you want to add a script into the spreadsheet, you can go in tools and then scripts, put in script code, and put appropriate triggers for when you want the script to run. Google Form submissions can be anonymous as well and you'll be able to set the privacy of that spreadsheet to anyone with link. You can choose in the form settings to show the option to view submissions after submitting form.

Comment: The thing is, I have the script for the spreadsheet, and it works for everyone except for the administrator. I'm just trying to figure out why.

Comment: The script for the spreadsheet only does either time trigger or submission/change with form/spreadsheet. Being the script administrator doesn't affect it. Since you say the script pushes data through a spreadsheet, you're saying you fill out the form and your submission isn't appearing in the spreadsheet correct?

Comment: It's just that the script isn't executable at all by the device admin